# Prop value not changing in child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I created a Error component that I show in a dialog when I get a error from my server. I pass the error msg I receive in the parent component to the error component through props. When I first show the error component by setting v-model="errorDialog" to true I see the correct error. When I try showing the dialog again with my error component I keep getting the same error message as when I first showed it ({{errMsg}} ). Even though the value of errMsg is different :err="errMsg". Any help?

error component.

```
<template>
     <v-card>
  <v-card-title class="headline red lighten-2" >
  Oh No 
  </v-card-title>
   <v-card-text>

         <b> {{errMsg}} </b>
   </v-card-text>

     <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>

            <v-btn color="#9da4cf" text @click="cancel">Ok</v-btn>

        </v-card-actions>

  </v-card>
</template>


<script>
export default {

    data(){

        return {

            errMsg:this.err
        }
    },

    props:{

        err:{
        type: String,
      required: true,

        }
    },

    methods:{

 cancel(){


       this.$emit('cancel-ErrorDialog');



      }

    }

}
</script>
```

from parent component

```
 <v-dialog v-model="errorDialog" max-width="600px">
      <ErrorDialog :err="errMsg" v-on:cancel-ErrorDialog="cancelErrorDialog" />
    </v-dialog>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value is being copied into the local data object when the component is first created, but it is never being updated. It looks like you can skip that `data` object entirely though and use the prop directly:

```js
<template>
     <v-card>
  <v-card-title class="headline red lighten-2" >
  Oh No 
  </v-card-title>
   <v-card-text>

         <b> {{err}} </b>
   </v-card-text>

     <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>

            <v-btn color="#9da4cf" text @click="cancel">Ok</v-btn>

        </v-card-actions>

  </v-card>
</template>


<script>
export default {

    props:{
      err:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
      }
    },

    methods:{
      cancel(){
        this.$emit('cancel-ErrorDialog');
      }
    }

}
</script>
```